# How can we return the number of common characters in two strings in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I want to search two character strings and return the number of common characters. So, if we have

```
s1 = "aabcc" 
s2 = "adcaa"
```

the output should be `solution(s1, s2) = 3`. (s1 and s2 have 3 common characters - 2 "a"s and 1 "c".)

My idea was to concatenate the two strings using paste and then to check the count of each distinct character in our new string. If the count is even, I would add half of that count to a count variable (so, if we have four a's, then we have two pairs), and if the count for some character is odd, then we take away one and add half of that number to our count (effectively disregarding the extra occurrence of the character that cannot be paired.

I thought maybe I could do this by getting our characters in a data.frame which recorded the count of each letter, but the code to do that is getting inordinately long:

```
df <- as.data.frame(paste(s1,s2,sep="") %>%
## keep first column only and name it     'characters':
select('characters' = 1) %>%
## multiple cell values (as separated by a   blank)
## into separate rows:
separate_rows(characters, sep = " ") %>%
group_by(characters) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
arrange(desc(count))
```

So i'm now thinking that I've overcomplicated this whole thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction? is my initial idea sensible or is it off the mark?

Clarification: Strings are not necessarily the same length, but they are both always between 1 and 14 characters long.

Clarification2: Ideally solutions will be in base R (no packages) because that is what I'm trying to get competent in first, but all other solutions still welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inner_join(as.data.frame(table(strsplit(s1, "") )),
          as.data.frame(table(strsplit(s2, "") )),
          by = "Var1") %>% 
  mutate(Freq.diff = pmin(Freq.x, Freq.y)) %>% 
  pull(Freq.diff) %>% 
  sum()
```

Or with just base R:

```
df <- merge(as.data.frame(table(strsplit(s1, ""))),
            as.data.frame(table(strsplit(s2, ""))),
            by = 1) 

sum(pmin(df$Freq.x, df$Freq.y))
```

Comment: strings are not necessarily the same length!

Comment: Ok, updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! I'm happy to know I wasn't a million miles away with my thinking (getting it in data frame and doing count). I will study this answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that first `strsplit()` the string, then use `vecsets::vintersect()` to output the intersecting characters (duplicated character will also be shown). Then output the `length` of the intersecting characters.

This should work with strings that have different length.

```
library(vecsets)

length(vintersect(strsplit(s1, "")[[1]], strsplit(s2, "")[[1]]))
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I had thought about using strsplit(), but couldn't get any further with it in base R. I wonder, out of interest, whether you see a way of implementing this same method with base r (no packages)?

Comment: Seems like @Lennyy has contributed a base R method. For me, I don't really know how to do it in base R with the "intersect" mindset. If you want to learn more, you can take a look at the code of `vintersect`, which also employs `intersect` from base R

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

s1 = "aabcc" 
s2 = "adcaa"

data.frame(x = table(str_split(s1,"", simplify = T)[1,])) %>% 
  inner_join(data.frame(x = table(str_split(s2,"", simplify = T)[1,])), by="x.Var1") %>% 
  apply(1, min) %>% as.numeric %>% sum

#> [1] 3
```